# Reference requests re: maltheism

Tags: theology

What are some philosophical texts on maltheism?

Maltheism is the belief that there is an Evil God who enjoys our suffering and is toying with us.

People also believe that there is a hell that was made by this god and will send us there after we die.

The god or deity is described as malicious and evil.

Is is an evil God likely to exist, given the amount of suffering that happens on our planet? I would expect that arguments about such likelihoods would be a normal point-of-entry into philosophical discussions of maltheism, considering the role of probabilistic reasoning in some arguments about God's existence, either on God's own terms or in relation to evil, etc.

Comment: Question seems very opinion-based, perhaps you could rephrase, as per this guide: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: René Descartes explores this topic with what he describes as the "evil demon", whose objective is to deceive him and distort his thoughts. You might be interested to research more

Comment: Aimarekin: Nice comment and highly relevant but Descartes's French does not grant the *mauvais génie* (or *malin génie*) the status of a God. In the French text Descartes refers to the evil demon as '*non point un vrai Dieu*'. The Latin text runs: '*non optimum Deum, fontem veritatis, sed genium aliquem malignum, eundemque   summe potentem et calidum*' - 'not God, who is supremely good and the source of truth, but rather some malicious demon of the utmost power and cunning*' (J. Cottingham, 'Meditations : Latin-English', Cambridge: CUP, 2013: 28-9.) Very good comment, though - definitely so.

Comment: Just to add: the French translation of the Meditations was done by Louis-Charles d'Albert, not by Descartes himself, though he approved the translation: Cottingham, xxxiv.